# Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.31

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I have a project which runs on Vue 3 and I am trying to install [vue-datepicker](https://vue3datepicker.com/).

But it fails to install the module and I can see the following error.

```
npm install @vuepic/vue-datepicker
```

```
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.1.2 -> 8.5.5
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.5
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.5.5 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myproject-spa@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.0.11
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peerOptional vue@"^2.6.10 || ^3.0.0" from @storybook/addon-docs@6.4.0-alpha.18
npm ERR!   node_modules/@storybook/addon-essentials/node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
npm ERR!     @storybook/addon-docs@"6.4.0-alpha.18" from @storybook/addon-essentials@6.4.0-alpha.18
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/addon-essentials
npm ERR!       dev @storybook/addon-essentials@"^6.4.0-alpha.18" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^3.0.0" from @storybook/vue3@6.4.0-alpha.18
npm ERR!   node_modules/@storybook/vue3
npm ERR!     peerOptional @storybook/vue3@"6.4.0-alpha.18" from @storybook/addon-docs@6.4.0-alpha.18
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/addon-essentials/node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
npm ERR!       @storybook/addon-docs@"6.4.0-alpha.18" from @storybook/addon-essentials@6.4.0-alpha.18
npm ERR!       node_modules/@storybook/addon-essentials
npm ERR!         dev @storybook/addon-essentials@"^6.4.0-alpha.18" from the root project
npm ERR!     dev @storybook/vue3@"^6.4.0-alpha.18" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@vue/babel-preset-app, @vue/compiler-sfc, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @vuepic/vue-datepicker@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.2.31
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@">=3.2.0" from @vuepic/vue-datepicker@3.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vuepic/vue-datepicker
npm ERR!     @vuepic/vue-datepicker@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
...
```

After that, I tried to use `--legacy-peer-deps` while installing the module, it seems that the module was successfully installed without an error, but I can't use the module due to the import error.

```
18 | import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

How can I fix this or resolve the module dependencies?

I am on node 16.14.0, npm 8.3.1 and ubuntu 20.

Comment: This problem seems specific to your project. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?